# How can I create some geometry for each material slot of an object with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible and if so how could I create a piece of geometry for every material slot in an object using Geometry Nodes modifier?

For example let's say I have a cube and it has 5 different material slots with different materials and I want to duplicate the cube itself, move it to the side and assign the material for each material slot:

[image]

So if I decided to add another material in a new material slot, another copy of the cube with the material would be created by the geometry nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way in *Geometry Nodes* to determine the currently assigned number of materials.

But if you can live with passing the number of materials via an integer value, then the following would be a solution:

[image]

1. Here I use a `Mesh Line`, where the distance between the points is set with the value *Offset*. The number of points here is set via the *Group Input*, which uses the number of your materials.
2. Then I simply instantiate the cube along these points.
3. So that I can assign a different material to each instance by index, I first use the `Capture Attribute` node on the *Instances* domain.
4. After I turn the instances into a mesh with `Realize Instances`, I can use this index directly in the node `Set Material Index`.

[image]

Comment: Cool! I can just add a driver to drive the modifier input field, create a variable out of object.material_slots and use len() function for that variable - that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!